# Huge Heap Blocks number in Postgres query planner

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am trying to tune a complex SQL query (can't post here due to organization policy). While going through query plan I found out that huge 'Heap scans' value spiking up query execution time and utilizing almost all the resources available in RDS.

I would like to know how I can bring it down to an acceptable value?

```
Aggregate  (cost=19967.440..19967.450 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=356827.833..356827.834 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=7783.550..19774.270 rows=765 width=80) (actual time=1396.970..356657.528 rows=1357 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.juliet_victor = kilo_sierra.quebec_seven)
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=7773.230..19760.700 rows=765 width=104) (actual time=1396.946..356647.666 rows=1357 loops=1)
                Hash Cond: (alpha_two.quebec_seven = mike_lima.hotel)
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=6407.130..18391.610 rows=765 width=128) (actual time=555.112..355801.185 rows=1357 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.quebec_seven = six_kilo.hotel)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5041.040..17022.640 rows=765 width=152) (actual time=90.547..355332.942 rows=1357 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3672.570..13310.410 rows=765 width=168) (actual time=90.527..1692.694 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3672.290..9707.350 rows=765 width=160) (actual time=89.430..648.944 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                        Hash Cond: (sierra(alpha_quebec.bravo) = three.quebec_seven)
                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3671.250..9607.780 rows=765 width=184) (actual time=88.918..643.314 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                              Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.foxtrot_sierra = romeo_lima.quebec_seven)
                                            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2666.800..8596.630 rows=765 width=208) (actual time=64.133..616.054 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                    Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.quebec_seven = yankee_tango_six.hotel)
                                                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1561.140..7469.930 rows=765 width=208) (actual time=59.295..604.672 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                          Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.quebec_seven = zulu_four.hotel)
                                                        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=454.600..6360.510 rows=765 width=208) (actual time=29.880..571.878 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                                Hash Cond: (sierra(alpha_quebec.foxtrot_yankee) = delta_whiskey.quebec_seven)
                                                              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on zulu_charlie alpha_quebec  (cost=191.900..5995.490 rows=765 width=232) (actual time=19.030..527.055 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                                      Recheck Cond: ((quebec_seven >= 'seven'::bytea) AND (quebec_seven <= 'mike_four'::bytea))
                                                                      Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                                      Heap Blocks: exact=804
                                                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on six_india  (cost=0.000..191.710 rows=1529 width=0) (actual time=17.534..17.534 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                                            Index Cond: ((quebec_seven >= 'seven'::bytea) AND (quebec_seven <= 'mike_four'::bytea))
                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=249.350..249.350 rows=1068 width=40) (actual time=6.931..6.931 rows=2153 loops=1)
                                                                      Buckets: 4096 (originally 2048)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 152kB
                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on two_oscar delta_whiskey  (cost=0.000..249.350 rows=1068 width=40) (actual time=0.844..5.628 rows=2153 loops=1)
                                                                            Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=1104.370..1104.370 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=29.408..29.409 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 22kB
                                                              ->  Subquery Scan on zulu_four  (cost=1100.050..1104.370 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=28.947..29.296 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1100.050..1102.640 rows=173 width=96) (actual time=28.945..29.203 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                            Group Key: juliet_xray.hotel
                                                                          ->  Sort  (cost=1100.050..1100.480 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=28.937..28.992 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                                  Sort Key: juliet_xray.hotel
                                                                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 46kB
                                                                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.430..1093.620 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=9.474..28.581 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                                        Hash Cond: (juliet_xray.romeo_zulu = romeo_three.quebec_seven)
                                                                                      ->  Seq Scan on charlie juliet_xray  (cost=0.000..1081.500 rows=788 width=64) (actual time=6.817..25.627 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                                              Filter: ((NOT whiskey_yankee) AND zulu_uniform)
                                                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 11474
                                                                                      ->  Hash  (cost=6.880..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=2.629..2.629 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                                                                                            ->  Seq Scan on lima romeo_three  (cost=0.000..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=0.840..2.569 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                                    Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1103.160..1103.160 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=4.822..4.822 rows=1305 loops=1)
                                                          Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 79kB
                                                        ->  Subquery Scan on yankee_tango_six  (cost=1099.160..1103.160 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=3.490..4.413 rows=1306 loops=1)
                                                              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1099.160..1101.160 rows=200 width=96) (actual time=3.489..3.893 rows=1306 loops=1)
                                                                      Group Key: india1.hotel
                                                                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=7.430..1098.300 rows=346 width=32) (actual time=0.086..2.867 rows=1391 loops=1)
                                                                            Hash Cond: (india1.romeo_zulu = six_lima1.quebec_seven)
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on charlie quebec_oscar_zulu_seven  (cost=0.000..1081.500 rows=1575 width=64) (actual time=0.003..2.086 rows=1306 loops=1)
                                                                                  Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 10449
                                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=6.880..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=0.067..0.067 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on lima victor_echo  (cost=0.000..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.039 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                        Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=847.740..847.740 rows=12537 width=40) (actual time=24.720..24.720 rows=23917 loops=1)
                                                    Buckets: 32768 (originally 16384)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1588kB
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on delta_juliet romeo_lima  (cost=0.000..847.740 rows=12537 width=40) (actual time=1.960..15.639 rows=23917 loops=1)
                                                          Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=1.020..1.020 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.481..0.481 rows=1 loops=1)
                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                            ->  Seq Scan on whiskey_november three  (cost=0.000..1.020 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.478..0.479 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                    Filter: ((NOT whiskey_yankee) AND ((two_charlie)::text = 'victor_lima'::text))
                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                ->  Index Scan using golf_sierra on quebec_oscar_zulu_papa alpha_two  (cost=0.290..4.700 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.761..0.765 rows=1 loops=1357)
                                        Index Cond: (quebec_seven = alpha_quebec.tango_yankee)
                                        Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1368.460..1371.520 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=218.485..260.014 rows=0 loops=1357)
                                  Hash Cond: (yankee_zulu.hotel = victor_hotel.quebec_seven)
                                ->  Unique  (cost=1361.850..1363.010 rows=137 width=7905) (actual time=450.463..644.573 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=1361.850..1362.430 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=450.461..524.690 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                              Sort Key: yankee_zulu.hotel
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on yankee_zulu  (cost=39.950..1352.740 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=25.050..203.538 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                                    Recheck Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'mike_papa'::text)
                                                    Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                    Heap Blocks: exact=1656634
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on four  (cost=0.000..39.890 rows=463 width=0) (actual time=23.773..23.773 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                                          Index Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'mike_papa'::text)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=6.600..6.600 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=1.350..1.350 rows=0 loops=1357)
                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                                      ->  Index Scan using november on xray victor_hotel  (cost=0.660..6.600 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=1.340..1.341 rows=0 loops=1357)
                                              Index Cond: (sierra(alpha_quebec.kilo_kilo) = quebec_seven)
                                              Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1364.380..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=464.550..464.551 rows=31262 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1997kB
                          ->  Subquery Scan on six_kilo  (cost=1361.850..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=398.701..450.745 rows=31262 loops=1)
                                ->  Unique  (cost=1361.850..1363.010 rows=137 width=7905) (actual time=398.700..432.354 rows=31262 loops=1)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=1361.850..1362.430 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=398.695..412.188 rows=31347 loops=1)
                                              Sort Key: five1.hotel
                                              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3217kB
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on yankee_zulu victor_zulu  (cost=39.950..1352.740 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=170.383..371.245 rows=31347 loops=1)
                                                    Recheck Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'kilo_six'::text)
                                                    Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                    Heap Blocks: exact=1272
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on four  (cost=0.000..39.890 rows=463 width=0) (actual time=169.794..169.794 rows=31347 loops=1)
                                                          Index Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'kilo_six'::text)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1364.380..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=841.806..841.806 rows=17638 loops=1)
                      Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1238kB
                    ->  Subquery Scan on mike_lima  (cost=1361.850..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=786.540..830.724 rows=17638 loops=1)
                          ->  Unique  (cost=1361.850..1363.010 rows=137 width=7905) (actual time=786.538..815.928 rows=17638 loops=1)
                                ->  Sort  (cost=1361.850..1362.430 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=786.536..797.997 rows=22005 loops=1)
                                        Sort Key: five2.hotel
                                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2488kB
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on yankee_zulu golf_november  (cost=39.950..1352.740 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=75.120..759.345 rows=22005 loops=1)
                                              Recheck Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'yankee_tango_papa'::text)
                                              Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                              Heap Blocks: exact=1810
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on four  (cost=0.000..39.890 rows=463 width=0) (actual time=74.894..74.894 rows=22005 loops=1)
                                                    Index Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'yankee_tango_papa'::text)
        ->  Hash  (cost=10.200..10.200 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
              ->  Seq Scan on tango_delta kilo_sierra  (cost=0.000..10.200 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
```

Some of the things I have tried so far:

1. `Vacuum full analyze`
2. `SET default_statistics_target = 1000;`
3. `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_all_tables order by n_tup_del;`

Comment: We have little to go by; maybe an obfuscated execution plan using https://explain.depesz.com would help. There is a misestimate (232 instead of 64383), but it is impossible to guess what is the problem with just this one node. Strange that PostgreSQL has to perform the exact same index scan 491 times.

Comment: It looks like your range table exceeds join_collapse_limit and/or from_collapse_limit and/or geqo_threshold. As a result, geqo kicks in. Try moving small parts of the query into CTE's (which should result in **small** resultsets), and refer tot hese

Comment: @wildplasser, let's say it was problem with settings then the same should happen everywhere but it happens in only one database among 1000's of identical databases

Comment: Well: throw it away, you'll still have 999 others! [sorry, it is **impossible to answer this question without** the actual query, the DDL, the settings, and some relevant  metrics]

Comment: Does the performance improve if you `SET enable_nestloop = off`?

Comment: It does improve tremendously but not sure if i would like to turn off nestloop though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem are the bad mis-estimates in the three index scans on `four` with the conditions `((kilo_two)::text = 'something'::text)`.

So if you

```
ALTER TABLE four ALTER kilo_two SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

(or maybe even higher values) and `ANALYZE` the table, the query plan should improve.

That will hopefully do away with the offending *Hash Right Join* that is so expensive, probably because it is repeated 491 times.

It would also help to use a partial index on `four`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON four ((kilo_two::text)) WHERE NOT whiskey_yankee;
```

If all else fails, you can force that one query to run without nested loop joins:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off;
SELECT /* your query */;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I did try your suggestions. As you can see we do have since query planner already using index to scan locations. Not sure why it chooses to loop so many times  and why it comes up with such an inaccurate estimates.

Comment: The bad estimates are probably the root of the problem. Even with `SET STATISTICS 10000` you don't get better estimates? Strange. I wonder if the obfuscation is hiding something. Are the values in the index scans frequent or rare values? What is the data type?

Comment: I increased my default_statistics_target to 5000 still nothing changed. They are frequent and data type is varchar

Comment: Just to be certain: you ran `ANALYZE` on the table after the change, right? If yes, I have no explanation.

Comment: I ran on whole database using vaccum analyze verbose

Comment: Ok, Just discovered i should run ANALYZE not vaccum analyze hence the latest statistics are not updated. Now the planner picks the right one

Comment: Hmm, `VACUUM ANALYZE` is the same as first `VACUUM`, then `ANALYZE`, so it shouldn't make a difference. But I asked you to `ANALYZE` that specific table.

Comment: not sure what was the reason really but when i did ANALYZE it started working.I thought VACUUM ANALYZE would anyway run ANALYZE so kept running VACUUM ANALYZE

Comment: Ok, now that you get better statistics, did anything change?

Comment: Yes. The query time reduced significantly from 3-5 mins to under a second.